apps script checkbox selections only sending 1st selection to google sheet?
I’m having an issue with my Google Apps Script for handling form submissions that include multiple checkbox selections (parcel ID). Specifically, I need to process all selected checkboxes and send their values to a Google Sheet, but currently, only the first selection is being processed.
Here’s a detailed overview of the problem, along with the relevant code I’m working with:
Problem Description
I have a form that allows users to select multiple checkboxes representing Parcel IDs. When the form is submitted, the selected Parcel IDs should be sent to a Google Sheet, but only the first selected checkbox value is being sent. I need to modify the existing code to ensure that all selected Parcel IDs are processed and recorded in the Google Sheet.
Here is the relevant code.gs
function removeDuplicateComments() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var commentsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Agent Notes");
  var dataRange = commentsSheet.getRange(2, 1, commentsSheet.getLastRow() - 1, commentsSheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  // Create an object to store unique rows
  var uniqueRows = {};
  var uniqueData = [];

  // Iterate through the rows and store unique rows in the object
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var key = row.join(",");
    uniqueRows[key] = row;
  }

  // Extract unique rows from the object
  for (var key in uniqueRows) {
    uniqueData.push(uniqueRows[key]);
  }

  // Clear the existing data from row 2 to the last row and write back the uniqueData
  commentsSheet.getRange(2, 1, commentsSheet.getLastRow() - 1, commentsSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  if (uniqueData.length > 0) {
    commentsSheet.getRange(2, 1, uniqueData.length, uniqueData[0].length).setValues(uniqueData);
  }
}

// Function to remove duplicate statuses
function removeDuplicateStatuses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var dataRange = statusSheet.getRange(3, 1, statusSheet.getLastRow() - 2, statusSheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  // Create an object to store unique rows
  var uniqueRows = {};
  var uniqueData = [];

  // Iterate through the rows and store unique rows in the object
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var key = row.join(",");
    uniqueRows[key] = row;
  }

  // Extract unique rows from the object
  for (var key in uniqueRows) {
    uniqueData.push(uniqueRows[key]);
  }

  // Clear the existing data from row 3 to the last row and write back the uniqueData
  statusSheet.getRange(3, 1, statusSheet.getLastRow() - 2, statusSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  if (uniqueData.length > 0) {
    statusSheet.getRange(3, 1, uniqueData.length, uniqueData[0].length).setValues(uniqueData);
  }
}

// Function to handle form submission
function handleFormSubmit(e) {
  // Your existing form submission logic
  
  // Call the sortSheets function after form submission
  sortSheets();
}

function doPost(e) {
  if (e && e.parameter) {
    // Extract parameters from the POST request
    var landowner = e.parameter.landowner ? e.parameter.landowner.toString() : '';
    var substation = e.parameter.substation ? e.parameter.substation.toString() : '';
    var comment = e.parameter.comment ? e.parameter.comment.toString() : '';
    var status = e.parameter.status ? e.parameter.status.toString() : '';
    var supervisor = e.parameter.supervisor ? e.parameter.supervisor.toString() : '';
    var date = e.parameter.datePicker ? e.parameter.datePicker : ''; // Updated from 'date'
    var parcelIds = e.parameter.parcelId ? e.parameter.parcelId : []; // Extract parcel IDs

    // Debugging: Log the parcelIds to check if they are received correctly
    Logger.log("Received parcelIds: " + parcelIds);

    // Ensure parcelIds is an array
    if (!Array.isArray(parcelIds)) {
      parcelIds = [parcelIds];
    }

    // Split string into an array if necessary
    if (typeof parcelIds === 'string') {
      parcelIds = parcelIds.split(',');
    }

    // Trim any extra whitespace for all parcel IDs
    parcelIds = parcelIds.map(parcelId => parcelId.trim()).filter(parcelId => parcelId); // Remove empty strings

    // Debugging: Log the cleaned parcelIds
    Logger.log("Processed parcelIds: " + parcelIds);

    // Loop through each parcel ID and add records
    for (var i = 0; i < parcelIds.length; i++) {
      var parcelId = parcelIds[i];

      if (parcelId) {
        addRecord(landowner, comment, date, supervisor, parcelId, substation); // Add record to Agent Notes
        addToStatuses(landowner, status, date, supervisor, parcelId, substation); // Add record to Statuses
      }
    }

    // Ensure that any duplicate statuses are removed after processing all parcel IDs
    removeDuplicateStatuses();

    // Generate the HTML output to confirm the records were added
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
    var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
    htmlOutput.message = 'Records Added';
    htmlOutput.subs = subs;

    return htmlOutput.evaluate();
  } else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: Invalid request parameters");
  }
}





function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.subs = subs;
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();

  // Retrieve parcel ID from the URL parameters, if available
  var parcelId = e.parameter.parcelId ? e.parameter.parcelId.toString() : '';
  if (parcelId) {
    htmlOutput.landownerInfo = getLandownerInfo(parcelId); // Pass parcelId to getLandownerInfo
  } else {
    htmlOutput.landownerInfo = ''; // Set landownerInfo to empty string if no parcelId provided
  }
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function getLandownerInfo(parcelid) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var commentsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Agent Notes");
  var headers = rawDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, rawDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var lastRow = rawDataSheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = rawDataSheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow - 1, rawDataSheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var landownerInfo = "";
  var maxComment = "N/A";
  var maxCommentDate = "N/A";

  var commentsDataRange = commentsSheet.getRange(2, 1, commentsSheet.getLastRow() - 1, commentsSheet.getLastColumn());
  var commentsValues = commentsDataRange.getValues();

  // Fetch the latest comment from Agent Notes using parcel ID
  for (var k = commentsValues.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (commentsValues[k][4] == parcelid && commentsValues[k][1]) { // Assuming parcel ID is in column E (index 4)
      maxCommentDate = Utilities.formatDate(commentsValues[k][2], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy"); // Assuming date is in column C (index 2)
      maxComment = commentsValues[k][1]; // Assuming comment is in column B (index 1)
      break;
    }
  }

  // Include comments in landownerInfo
  if (maxComment !== "N/A") {
    landownerInfo += "Comments: [" + maxCommentDate + "] " + maxComment + "\n\n";
  }

  // Fetch and include data from Raw Data
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][20] == parcelid) {
      var rowData = values[i];

      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        if ([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 20].indexOf(j) !== -1) {
          landownerInfo += headers[j] + ": " + rowData[j] + "\n";
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  return landownerInfo;
}

// Function to get parcel IDs by landowner
function getParcelIdsByLandowner(landowner) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var landownerColumn = rawDataSheet.getRange('D3:D' + rawDataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var parcelIdColumn = rawDataSheet.getRange('U3:U' + rawDataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var matchingParcelIds = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < landownerColumn.length; i++) {
    if (landownerColumn[i] === landowner) {
      matchingParcelIds.push(parcelIdColumn[i]);
    }
  }

  return matchingParcelIds;
} 
function getDistinctSubstations(supervisor) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var lastRow = rawDataSheet.getLastRow();
  var supervisors = rawDataSheet.getRange('W3:W' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var substations = rawDataSheet.getRange('E3:E' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  
  var distinctSubstations = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < supervisors.length; i++) {
    if (supervisors[i] === supervisor && substations[i] !== "" && !distinctSubstations.includes(substations[i])) {
      distinctSubstations.push(substations[i]);
    }
  }
  return distinctSubstations;
}
// Function to get parcels for a specific substation
function getParcels(substation) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var lastRow = rawDataSheet.getLastRow();
  var substationValues = rawDataSheet.getRange('E3:E' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var landownerValues = rawDataSheet.getRange('D3:D' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var filteredLandowners = [];
  var uniqueLandowners = new Set();

  for (var i = 0; i < substationValues.length; i++) {
    if (substationValues[i] === substation && landownerValues[i]) {
      uniqueLandowners.add(landownerValues[i]);
    }
  }

  filteredLandowners = Array.from(uniqueLandowners);

  return filteredLandowners;
}
function updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo() {
  var selectedParcelIds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#parcelIdContainer input[type=checkbox]:checked"))
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

  if (selectedParcelIds.length > 0) {
    // Call updateMaxStatusForParcel with all selected Parcel IDs
    selectedParcelIds.forEach(parcelId => {
      updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcelId);

      // Call getLandownerInfo with all selected Parcel IDs
      getLandownerInfo(parcelId);
    });
  }
}

// Function to get the maximum status row for a specific parcel ID
function getMaxStatusRowForParcel(parcelId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var lastRow = statusSheet.getLastRow();
  var parcelIdValues = statusSheet.getRange('E4:E' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var statusValues = statusSheet.getRange('B4:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var maxRow = -1;

  for (var i = parcelIdValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (parcelIdValues[i] == parcelId) {
      maxRow = i + 4; // Adding 4 because we start from row 4 in the sheet
      break;
    }
  }

  return maxRow;
}

// Function to get the maximum status for a specific parcel ID
function getMaxStatusForParcel(parcelId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var maxRow = getMaxStatusRowForParcel(parcelId);

  if (maxRow != -1) {
    var status = statusSheet.getRange('B' + maxRow).getValue();
    return status;
  } else {
    return ""; // Return empty string if no matching row found
  }
}

function addRecord(landowner, comment, date, supervisor, parcelId, substation) {
  var dateObject = new Date(date);
  dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getDate() + 1);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateObject, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Agent Notes");
  dataSheet.appendRow([landowner, comment, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId, substation]);

  var backupSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18WoL47QOLH8Xx3vdbiaLBvhoIJSc6HhfObsnKj9GrKM");
  var backupCommentsSheet = backupSS.getSheetByName("Comments");
  backupCommentsSheet.appendRow([landowner, comment, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId, substation]);
}


function addToStatuses(landowner, status, date, supervisor, parcelId, substation) {
  var dateObject = new Date(date);
  dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getDate() + 1);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateObject, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  statusSheet.appendRow([landowner, status, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId, substation]);

  var backupSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18WoL47QOLH8Xx3vdbiaLBvhoIJSc6HhfObsnKj9GrKM");
  var backupStatusesSheet = backupSS.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  backupStatusesSheet.appendRow([landowner, status, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId, substation]);
}

// Function to sort specified ranges in "statuses" and "Agent Notes" worksheets
function sortSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GAiSqvWV1-G3VBnksWVxwErWhd4UAIblJsGkkiTA0GY");

  // Sort "statuses" worksheet
  var statusesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("statuses");
  var statusesRange = statusesSheet.getRange("A4:F" + statusesSheet.getLastRow());
  statusesRange.sort({ column: 3, ascending: true });

  // Sort "Agent Notes" worksheet
  var agentNotesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Agent Notes");
  var agentNotesRange = agentNotesSheet.getRange("A4:F" + agentNotesSheet.getLastRow());
  agentNotesRange.sort({ column: 3, ascending: true });
}

// Function to get the URL of the web app
function getUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}

html/js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <title>Daily Contact Form</title>
  <style>
    /* Your CSS styles here */
    body {
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: #f0f8ff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Light blue background color */
    }
    body::before {
      content: "";
      background: url('https://i.imgur.com/H49QJct.jpeg') no-repeat center center fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      opacity: 1.0; /* 50% opacity */
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .container {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
      text-align: center; /* Center the content inside the container */
      padding-top: 20px; /* Add space at the top */
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* Semi-transparent background */
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    h1 {
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add space between header image and header text */
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    select {
      width: 50%; /* Set the width of dropdown menus to fill the container */
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for dropdown values */
      text-align-last: center; /* Align dropdown selections in the middle */
    }
    /* Additional styling to center-align dropdown selections */
    option {
      text-align: center;
    }
    textarea {
      height: 100px;
      width: 250px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 100%; /* Set font size for textarea */
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for submit button */
    }
    .submit-message {
      color: red;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .landowner-info {
      float: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      width: 97%; /* Extend size of landowner info box */
    }
    #parcelIdContainer input[type=checkbox] {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Function to set the default date to today's date
    function setDefaultDate() {
      var today = new Date();
      var day = today.getDate();
      var month = today.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero indexed
      var year = today.getFullYear();

      // Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD for the input field
      var formattedDate = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

      // Set the default value of the date picker input field directly
      var datePicker = document.getElementById("datePicker");
      datePicker.setAttribute("value", formattedDate);

      // Set the value of the text box to the same date
      datePicker.value = formattedDate;
    }

    function updateSubstations(supervisor) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(substations) {
        var substationDropdown = document.getElementById("substation");
        substationDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        substationDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Populate Substation dropdown with matching substations
        substations.forEach(function(substation) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = substation;
          option.text = substation;
          substationDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Select the previously selected substation if available
        var savedSubstation = localStorage.getItem("substation");
        if (savedSubstation && substations.includes(savedSubstation)) {
          substationDropdown.value = savedSubstation;
        }
      }).getDistinctSubstations(supervisor); // Call server function to get matching substations
    }

    function updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo() {
      var selectedParcelIds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#parcelIdContainer input[type=checkbox]:checked"))
        .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

      if (selectedParcelIds.length > 0) {
        // Call updateMaxStatusForParcel with the first selected Parcel ID
        updateMaxStatusForParcel(selectedParcelIds[0]);

        // Call getLandownerInfo with the first selected Parcel ID
        getLandownerInfo(selectedParcelIds[0]);
      }
    }

    function updateParcelInfo(landowner) {
      // Trigger search in "Raw Data" worksheet for landowner value
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcelIds) {
        var parcelIdContainer = document.getElementById("parcelIdContainer");
        parcelIdContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous checkboxes

        // Populate Parcel ID checkboxes with matching rows from columns U3:U
        parcelIds.forEach(function(parcelId) {
          var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
          checkbox.type = "checkbox";
          checkbox.name = "parcelId";
          checkbox.value = parcelId;
          checkbox.id = parcelId;
          checkbox.addEventListener("change", updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo);

          var label = document.createElement("label");
          label.htmlFor = parcelId;
          label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parcelId));

          parcelIdContainer.appendChild(checkbox);
          parcelIdContainer.appendChild(label);
          parcelIdContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        });
      }).getParcelIdsByLandowner(landowner); // Call server function to get matching parcel IDs
    }

    function getLandownerInfo(parcel) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(landownerInfo) {
        document.getElementById("landowner-info-content").innerText = landownerInfo;
      }).getLandownerInfo(parcel);
    }

    function getParcels(substation) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcels) {
        var parcelDropdown = document.getElementById("parcel");
        parcelDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Sort the parcel options alphabetically
        parcels.sort().forEach(function(parcel) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcel;
          option.text = parcel;
          parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Update parcel info immediately after selecting a parcel
        var selectedParcel = parcelDropdown.value;
        updateParcelInfo(selectedParcel);
      }).getParcels(substation);
    }

    function updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(maxStatus) {
        var statusDropdown = document.getElementById("status");
        statusDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options

        // Define status options in the desired order
        var statusOptions = ["", "Assigned to Agent", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Pledged", "Signed", "Dropped"];

        // Add options to the dropdown in the defined order
        statusOptions.forEach(function(status) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = status;
          option.text = status;
          if (status === maxStatus) {
            option.selected = true; // Select the option if it matches the max status
          }
          statusDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
    }

    function saveSubmittedValues() {
      var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
      var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;

      // Save submitted values to local storage
      localStorage.setItem("supervisor", supervisor);
      localStorage.setItem("substation", substation);
    }

    function prefillDropdowns() {
      // Retrieve saved values from local storage
      var supervisor = localStorage.getItem("supervisor");
      var substation = localStorage.getItem("substation");

      // Pre-fill supervisor dropdown
      if (supervisor) {
        document.getElementById("supervisor").value = supervisor;
        // Trigger the onchange event of supervisor dropdown to update substation dropdown
        updateSubstations(supervisor);
      }

      // Pre-fill substation dropdown
      if (substation) {
        document.getElementById("substation").value = substation;
        // Trigger the onchange event of substation dropdown to populate parcels
        getParcels(substation);
      }
    }

    function validateForm() {
      var isValid = true;
      var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
      var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
      var parcelIdCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#parcelIdContainer input[type=checkbox]:checked");
      var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
      var date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;
      var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

      // Collect all selected parcel IDs
      var parcelIds = Array.from(parcelIdCheckboxes).map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

      // Check if any field is null or blank
      if (!supervisor || !substation || parcelIds.length === 0 || !status || !date || !comment) {
        document.getElementById("submit-message").innerText = "All fields must be filled.";
        return false; // Prevent form submission
      }

      // Save submitted values to local storage
      saveSubmittedValues();

      // Set the parcel IDs as a comma-separated string
      document.getElementById("parcelId").value = parcelIds.join(',');

      // Call server-side function to sort sheets after form submission
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
        // Form submission will only proceed after sorting is done
        document.forms[0].submit();
      }).sortSheets();

      // Disable form submit button to prevent resubmission
      document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;

      return false; // Prevent default form submission to wait for sorting
    }

    // Prevent form resubmission popup on page reload
    if (window.history.replaceState) {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
      });
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      setDefaultDate();
      prefillDropdowns();
    };

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/16QsZja.png" alt="Header Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px;">

    <h1>Daily Contact Form</h1>

    <form method="post" action="<?= getUrl() ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

      <label><strong>Land Agent</strong></label><br>
      <select name="supervisor" id="supervisor" onchange="updateSubstations(this.value)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
        <option value="Ian">Ian</option>
        <option value="Parker">Parker</option>
        <option value="Scott">Scott</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label><strong>Substation</strong></label><br>
      <select name="substation" id="substation" onchange="getParcels(this.value)">
        <option value=""></option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label><strong>Landowner</strong></label><br>
      <select name="landowner" id="parcel" onchange="updateParcelInfo(this.value)">
        <!-- Parcel dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <div id="parcelIdContainer">
      </div>

      <label><strong>Status</strong></label><br>
      <select name="status" id="status">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Assigned to Agent">Assigned to Agent</option>
        <option value="Outreach">Outreach</option>
        <option value="Negotiating">Negotiating</option>
        <option value="Pledged">Pledged</option>
        <option value="Signed">Signed</option>
        <option value="Dropped">Dropped</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label><strong>Date</strong></label><br>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="datePicker"><br><br>

      <label><strong>Comment</strong></label><br>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br><br>

      <input type="hidden" name="parcelId" id="parcelId" value="" /> <!-- Hidden field to hold the selected parcel IDs -->
      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />
      <span id="submit-message" class="submit-message"></span>
    </form>

    <div class="landowner-info">
      <h2>Landowner Info</h2>
      <p id="landowner-info-content"></p> <!-- Display landowner information -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


I understand that you are deploying a Web App from Apps Script and you want to send the checkbox data to a Google Sheet from the HTML form.
I created a simple example case where there are three checkboxes (options 1, 2 & 3) to separate the issue, and you can click on a Submit button which parses all of the selections to the Google Sheet.
Here is the index.html Apps Script file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target = "_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <form id = "checkboxForm">
      <input type = "checkbox" name = "Checkbox" value = "Checkbox 1"> Checkbox 1</br>
      <input type = "checkbox" name = "Checkbox" value = "Checkbox 2"> Checkbox 2</br>
      <input type = "checkbox" name = "Checkbox" value = "Checkbox 3"> Checkbox 3</br>
      <button type = "button" onclick = "submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      function submitForm() {

        var form = document.getElementById('checkboxForm');
        var checkboxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[name="Checkbox"]:checked');
        var values = [];

        checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
          values.push(checkbox.value);
        });

        google.script.run.appendValuesToSheet(values);

      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>

Now, for the Code.gs script itself:
function doGet() {

   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');

}

function appendValuesToSheet(values) {

  var sheetId = '14RAl4WemBx-1I3u3C2Ut-ggKTAGnBaBI4MtNE67eT6M';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(values);

}


Hey I tried incorporating your idea and still getting stuck. I added in the entire code.gs and html side. is there anything glaringly obvious you see that im doing wrong? It is working outside of the first checkbox data being sent
